# The object invoked has disconnected from its clients when VBA copy-pasting ranges from sheet to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first time posting here. I've tried searching up a fix to no avail. I am not an expert at VBA so I am sure my code looks sloppy.

Basically, I am trying to copy and paste data from one sheet to another in the same workbook. The data to be copied is laid out like a table. The range where I am pasting to is a single row for one company.

```
Sub Save()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Integer
x = Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("B37").Value

'date
Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & x) = Date

'policy number
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L5").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("H" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("H" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'status
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L6").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("G" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'producer
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L7").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("EX" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("EX" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'primary
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D10:L10").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'1xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D11:L11").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("R" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("R" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'2xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D12:L12").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("AA" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("AA" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'3xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D13:L13").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("AJ" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("AJ" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'4xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D14:L14").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("AS" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("AS" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'5xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D15:L15").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("BB" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("BB" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'6xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D16:L16").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("BK" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("BK" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'7xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D17:L17").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("BT" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("BT" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'8xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D18:L18").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("CC" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("CC" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'9xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D19:L19").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("CL" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("CL" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'10xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D20:L20").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("CU" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("CU" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'11xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D21:L21").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("DD" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("DD" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'12xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D22:L22").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("DM" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("DM" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'13xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D23:L23").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("DV" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("DV" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'14xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D24:L24").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("EE" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("EE" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'15xs
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D25:L25").Copy
Worksheets("Data").Range("EN" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Data").Range("EN" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

'clearborders
Sheets("Data").Activate
Range("A1:EX5000").Select
Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Range("A1").Select

'reformula below

'date
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("L27").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L27").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'policy number
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("L5").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'status
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("L6").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'producer
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("L7").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'primary
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D10:L10").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'1XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D11:L11").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'2XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D12:L12").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'3XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D13:L13").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'4XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D14:L14").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'5XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D15:L15").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'6XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D16:L16").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D16").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'7XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D17:L17").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'8XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D18:L18").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'9XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D19:L19").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D19").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'10XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D20:L20").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'11XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D21:L21").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D21").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'12XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D22:L22").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D22").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'13XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D23:L23").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'14XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D24:L24").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D24").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

'15XS
Worksheets("Reformula").Range("D25:L25").Copy
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D25").PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This code worked for a while, but I added the "Status" column and that's when everything seemed to fall apart. The macro hangs and then spits out the error. When debugging, the yellow highlight is always on a "Paste:=xlPasteFormats" line.

I would appreciate any insight into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Move `Paste:=xlPasteFormats` to the line `Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D25").PasteSpecial` so it reads

```
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("D25").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

That being said, you could also replace all those copy paste operations and just do

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("H" & x) = Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L5")
```

And repeat for each range you're copying.

And for the formulas

```
Worksheets("Insurance Tower Template").Range("L27") = Worksheets("Reformula").Range("L27").Formula
```

And repeat for each formula you're copying just to clean the code up a bit and reduce performance heavy `Copy-Paste` operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tate, unfortunately before the reformula section, I need to maintain the formatting and the values.

Comment: Happy to have helped!